# how to fix liquibase can not create index on oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, error-handling, liquibase

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - preConditions:
  - changeSet:
      id: 8
      author: myname
      context: context
      changes:
        - createIndex:
            tableName: table_name
            indexname: index_name
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: column_1
```

Get an error:

> DatabaseException: ORA-00953: missing or invalid index name
>   [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX ON SYSTEM.CABLEMODEMTERMINATIONSYSTEM(KMA_ID)]

Comment: I can see the INDEX NAME is missing in this statement.

Comment: please don't create objects in the SYSTEM schema

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `indexname`, it should be `indexName` (upper-case N).